# Bar chart (chart.js) with only 2 points does not show one of the bars

Tags: chart.js

I have a strange behavior that seems like a bug to me. I have a bar chart with one dataset with 2 points, but 1 is not shown, though it works fine with 3 or with horizontal bar e.g.

[image]

[image]

Is it a known bug of some kind that can be worked around? It seems that the chart does not scale itself well enough and one of the bars is below the "visibility point" somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was apparently that the Y-axis started not at 0 by default. It's possible to add an option for that:

```
options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```